# How to repeat (or recurse) until there are no warnings?

Tags: r, warnings

Suppose that

1. the result of `foo()` changes with each invocation (e.g. `foo` it uses a PRNG, or downloads ephemeral data from some server, etc.);
2. evaluating `foo()` *sometimes* produces warnings; and
3. *some* (not all!) of these warnings are "serious", meaning that the result just returned by `foo()` is to be considered invalid.

Here's a ***toy*** example:

```
foo <- function () {
    n = 10

    fake.data <- list(x = rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                      y = rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = 0.3))

    model <- glm(formula = y ~ x,
                 family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                 data = fake.data)

    coef(model)[[2]]
}
```

So,

```
set.seed(10); foo()
## [1] -1.369938

set.seed(2); foo()
## [1] 52.89538
## Warning message:
## glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

set.seed(23); foo()
## [1] 1673.609
## Warning messages:
## 1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
## 2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

foo()
## [1] 0.5127775
```

Let's say that, in the case of this `foo`, of the two types of warnings shown in the sample output above, only those of the form

```
glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
```

are to be considered "serious" (as defined in (3) above).

---

Now, I want to define a function `bar` that returns the result of the first `foo()` call for which there were no "serious" warnings.

Also, to help with this demonstration, I'll define the following helper function to set the PRNG's seed (for reproducibility) and immediately invoke `bar`:

```
baz <- function (seed) {
    set.seed(seed)
    bar()
}
```

With `baz` does defined, if `bar` works as desired, the expression `c(baz(10), baz(23), baz(2))` should evaluate to

```
[1] -1.3699380  0.5127775 52.8953800
```

In particular, the second value in this vector, corresponding to `baz(23)`, should equal the result of the *second* call to `foo()` after setting the seed to 23 (since the first such call would have produced a "serious" warning).

---

My first thought<sup>1</sup> for `bar` was this:

```
bar <- function () {

    result <- foo()

    if (!is.null(warnings()) &&
        "glm.fit: algorithm did not converge" %in% names(last.warning)) {
        cat("doing over\n")
        return (bar())
    }

    result
}
```

This does not work.  For example,

```
c(baz(10), baz(23), baz(2))
## [1]   -1.369938 1673.608858   52.895383
```

Note that the value for `baz(23)` was 1673.608858, not 0.5127775.

Furthermore, if I now evaluate `baz(10)` again, not only I don't get the expected result, -1.369938, but in fact I get no result, because the call goes into an infinite recursion.

This suggest that the `last.warning` from the previous execution of `foo` is still around.

So I tried this:

```
bar <- function () {

    assign("last.warning", NULL, envir = baseenv())

    result <- foo()

    if (!is.null(warnings()) &&
        "glm.fit: algorithm did not converge" %in% names(last.warning)) {
        cat("doing over\n")
        return (bar())
    }

    result
}
```

This avoids the infinite recursion, but `baz(23)` still produces the (wrong) result, 1673.608858.

---

**Q1:** How can I write `bar` so that `baz(23)` returns 0.5127775, and `baz` never falls into an infinite recursion?

**Q2:** Is there a way to suppress the printing of warnings to the terminal without losing `bar`'s ability to detect "serious" warnings during the execution of `foo()`?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>AFAICT, `tryCatch` won't work here, because a `warning` handle would result in a recursive call whenever there is *any warning at all*, whether it is "serious" or not.  I don't see how the `warning` handle could return the correct value when a only non-serious warning occurs.</sup>

Comment: If you error on warning, you could use `testthat::try_again`, though you'll have to set a maximum number of tries (which is probably a good idea anyway).

Comment: @alistaire: please correct me I'm wrong but erroring on warnings seems to me to have the same problem as with `tryCatch`: it cannot distinguish "serious" warnings from the rest.

Comment: Sure it can, you just need to build a more specific warning handler, e.g. `tryCatch(warning('foo'), warning = function(w){if(w %in% c('foo', 'bar')) stop('serious warning')})`

Comment: @alistaire: I have a hard time following your suggestion.  If you have an idea of how to implement `bar`, please post it as an answer, so that I can test it.  That's the reason I posted working toy example.